# retrieving values from table itself with arrays (pyspark)

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

policies table:

Columns : pol_no, version, version_number,base,permitted_usage,discount_group,vehicle_age,rf_1,rf_2,rf_3

rf_1, rf_2 and rf_3 values are array values.

For instance, rf_1 = ["base","permitted_usage"]

Need to match the array values with the column names in policies table, retrieve the value and append it to rl_1 as an array as well.

Repeating these steps for the rest of the rf_index columns and append it to rl_index columns

| pol_no | base | permitted_usage | claims | discount | rf_1 | rf_2 | rl_1 | rl_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 500 | private | 0 | Y | ['base','permitted_usage'] | ['discount'] | [500,'private'] | ['Y'] |
| 2 | 600 | business | 1 | N | ['base','permitted_usage' | ['discount'] | [600,'business'] | ['N'] |

thats how the final ouput should look like.

*please note that in the future there can be more RF columns rf_4,5,6 etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamically select the `rf` columns

```
from itertools import chain

cols = df.select(df.colRegex(r'`rf_\d+`')).columns

# ['rf_1', 'rf_2']
```

Create a mapping which maps column name to corresponding column value for a given row.

```
mapping = F.create_map(*chain(*[(F.lit(c), F.col(c)) for c in df.drop(*cols).columns]))

# Column<'map(pol_no, pol_no, base, base, permitted_usage, permitted_usage, claims, claims, discount, discount)'>
```

For each `rf` column, apply a transformation function on the items inside the list to substitute the matching values from the mapping

```
new_cols = [F.transform(c, lambda v: mapping[v]).alias(c.replace('f', 'l')) for c in cols]
result = df.select('*', *new_cols)

# +------+----+---------------+------+--------+--------------------+----------+---------------+----+
# |pol_no|base|permitted_usage|claims|discount|                rf_1|      rf_2|           rl_1|rl_2|
# +------+----+---------------+------+--------+--------------------+----------+---------------+----+
# |     1| 500|        private|     0|       Y|[base, permitted_...|[discount]| [500, private]| [Y]|
# |     2| 600|       business|     1|       N|[base, permitted_...|[discount]|[600, business]| [N]|
# +------+----+---------------+------+--------+--------------------+----------+---------------+----+
```

Comment: it works but however it is not following the datatype and assuming everything are strings for the array values but i would like to keep the same datatypes as in individual columns

Comment: Its not possible since the spark array can only have homogeneous types :)